# Simple tag replacement with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a *very* simple tag replacement problem that I'm trying to solve with BeatifulSoup's `replace_with` method but I'm having trouble understanding how this is supposed to work. I have the string `'<b>This is text</b>'` and I'd like to simply convert this to `'<bold>This is text</bold>'`. It seems like bs4's `replace_with` command should be able to do this, but it's not working like I'd expect. I tried (among some other variants) things like this:

```
>>> a = '<b>This is text</b>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(a, 'html.parser')
>>> new_tag = soup.new_tag('bold')
>>> soup.b.replace_with(new_tag)
<b>This is text</b>
>>> soup
<bold></bold>
```

As you can see, the tags got replaced but then I lost the text. I can do this sort of thing with a string replacement but I'd really like to understand why this doesn't work as I tend to run into similar issues with bs4 with other methods and I must misunderstand something fundamental here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `.replace_with` you're replacing the whole tag with new one - and the new one doesn't have any content(text). Try instead:

```py
a = "<b>This is text</b>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(a, "html.parser")

soup.b.name = "bold"

print(soup)
```

Prints:

```html
<bold>This is text</bold>
```

Comment: Oh. That makes a lot of sense. Thanks.